# Equation of tangent to surface

Tags: geometry, 3d

Equation of the tangent to the curve x=t,y=t^2,z=t^3 at its point M(1,1,1) is :(t=1) . I am confused with the fact that since this is a surface z=xy,therefore the equation should be of a plane but the answer given is a straight line in 3-d. I have also searched on google and where i found that they are taking it as vector r(t)=  .

Comment: Now please tell me how to proceed

Comment: The answer is a line, not a plane (as stated below) and you say you know what that line is. Look up how to find a tangent line to a curve to check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec r(t)=(t,t^2,t^3)$

$\vec r'(t)=(1,2t,3t^2)$

$\vec u=\vec r'(1)=(1,2,3)$

the tangent line (red in the picture) at $A(1,1,1)$ is $A+s\vec u=(1+s,1+2s,1+3s)$

The curve is in blue

[image]

Comment: I am unable to understand first two steps how are you differentiating r(t)=(t, t^2,t^3)

Comment: Try here http://mathinsight.org/parametrized_curve_tangent_line_examples

Answer (score 0):

The equation you give, $[t,t^2,t^3]$ is the [equation of a curve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+(t,t%5E2,t%5E3)), not of a surface (because it has only one parameter, $t$. A surface would have two parameters). It has a tangent line, not a tangent plane.